# mysql-How to handle query search with \(backslash)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i have inserted a column in mysql table with `backslash(\)`like `user\12345`.But when i see in the table values i am not seeing the `forward slash(\)`. I am just seeing **user12345**.

When i query the just inserted row with `backslash(\)` with the below possible ways, i am always getting the zero records.

```
select * from users where user='user12345'
select * from users where user='user\12345'
select * from users where user='user\\12345'
```

when i copy paste the column value into notepad+ i could see there is a carriage retun in the end of every column values. user12345CRLF, as of now i can't update/remove the carriage return. but i want to fetch the records with carriage return. how can i do this?

I don't want to use like query, and i want to query for the exact username. how can i do this?

Comment: How did you insert the \ character? (which is a _backslash_, not a forward one) Does `SELECT * FROM users` display the character? It is possible it was not inserted to begin with, if misinterpreted as an escape character.

Comment: Unless you escaped the backslash when you inserted, the backslash will be treated as just escaping the character after it, it won't be inserted into the table.

Comment: `select * from users where user='user\\12345'` 

works fine for me. Are you sure there is a user called user\12345?

Comment: Try `where user like 'user%12345'`, do you see it there?

Comment: nope. select * from users is not bringing up any back slash. it just shows like user12345 instead of user\12345. But the same table shows back slash when i insert column with double back slash like user\\12345.

Comment: I am not seeing user\12345 in my table. as mike & barmar mentioned it has been treated as escape character. now my question is how can i fetch my records which has been inserted as escape character or something like that?

Comment: @Barmar, i have tried your query, where user like 'user%12345' and not getting any result :( kindly help

Comment: When I insert `"user\12345"`, it just inserts `user12345`. I don't know why you can't find it.

Comment: See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8b0e/1

Comment: You tagged this with `mysql-error-1064`. Did you get an error when you tried to insert it? That may be why you can't find it.

Comment: when i copy paste the column value into notepad+ i could see there is a carriage retun in the end of every column values. user12345CRLF, as of now i can't update/remove the carriage return. but will i want to fetch the records with carriage return. how can i do this?

Comment: @Barmar, can you please help me on my updated query?

Comment: You can use escape sequences: `CR = \r`, `LF = \n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash character \ is used for escape sequence. when you insert value like 'user\12345' then by default mysql server takes it as '\1' as escape character but it is not any special character so it discard the \ from the string.

```
Hitesh> update test set fname='user\344';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
Hitesh> select fname from test;
+---------+
| fname   |
+---------+
| user344 |
| user344 |
+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to store \ in string then you should use \

```
Hitesh> update test set fname='user\\344';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

Hitesh> select fname from test;
+----------+
| fname    |
+----------+
| user\344 |
| user\344 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you don't want to set  \ as escape character then you can enable the sql mode NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES.

```
Hitesh> SET sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> update test set fname='user\344';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Hitesh> select fname from test;
+----------+
| fname    |
+----------+
| user\344 |
| user\344 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

for case of carriage return to end of column, in query you can find the string which ends with \r in where clause and select column you can skip the last character which is \r

```
 Hitesh> set @@sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

 Hitesh> update test set fname='user344\r';
 Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.17 sec)
 Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0  

 Hitesh> select left( fname, CHAR_LENGTH(fname)-1) as fname from test where fname like '%\r';
    +---------+
    | fname   |
    +---------+
    | user344 |
    | user344 |
    +---------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Hitesh. In my case somehow there is a carriage return has been appended to the column in the end. how do i fetch column which has carriage return values at the end.

Comment: @user5050407 why don't you use the query like "select fname from test where fname like '%\r';"

Comment: thanks a ton for your help. Can't do exact match select instead of like query when i have escape sequence in my table?

Comment: I want to do exact match search instead like search, is this possible on this scenario?

Comment: Thanks a ton Hitesh again. I figured it out the query for exact match search. select * from users where user='user12345\r'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton @Hitesh,@Barmar again. I figured it out the query for exact match search. `select * from users where user='user12345\r'`